# OpenAPI Generator - Java 11 Native HTTP Client template: how to add custom headers

Tags: java, openapi-generator

I'm using OpenAPI Generator to generate a Java 11 HTTP Client for a swagger-compliant service.

The thing is: this service requires basic authentication but it doesn't challenge the client with a `WWW-Authenticate` header, so the Java 11 HTTP Client won't send the basic authentication configured with the builder. The workaround for this is to add the `Authorization` header directly in the request, as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54208946/4841508).

Now: as of version 4.3.1, OpenAPI Generator won't expose me an interface to customize the HTTP requests, so I'm wondering if it would be best to override the responsible template ([api.mustache:126](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/003165c2c254ded7817760cc1d6f97af730d9d4d/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/native/api.mustache#L126)) or if there is a cleaner alternative for this task.

Answer (score 3):

I come with same issue as yours and solution for me was using generated `ApiClient` class and its `RequestInterceptor` field. It allows to customize request headers prior sending it to server:

```java
ApiClient client = new ApiClient();
client.setRequestInterceptor(new Consumer<HttpRequest.Builder>() {
  @Override
  public void accept(HttpRequest.Builder builder) {
    builder.header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("foo:bar"));
  }
});
```

There is also a backing version of above called response interceptor if you need to capture reply headers.

Answer (score 0):

I started generating with the `native` library and got the same problem.
You should use the `setRequestInterceptor` method and
instead of using an anonymous class you can pass a lambda function

```
String access_token = System.getenv("access_token");
ApiClient client = new ApiClient();
client.setRequestInterceptor(r -> r.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token));
```